# PL/SQL script to loop through records to get all records with condition

Tags: database, select, plsql

I am trying to create a PL/SQL script to generate number of in a country based on these conditions:

- Country
- Nature of travel
- Year
- Length of Stay

  - More than 1 month
  - Less than 1 week
  - More than 1 week but less than 1 month

The final goal is to get something like this (for 1 year / 1 country):

[image]

I have tried to do the manual way (**takes me a long time**) of generate single SQL statements but I am unsure how to do it via a **PL/SQL loop**. Appreciate if anyone can show me how.

Below is the table structure in my database with the relevant fields.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Could You provide some sample data (f.e. on pastebin.com) like scripts to create databases with some data? It could be done without PL/SQL and it wouldn't take so much time.

Answer (score 0):

SQL

```
select c.country_name as country,
       a.nature_of_travel,
       case d.rn 
         when 1 then 'More than 1 month' 
         when 2 then 'Less than 1 week' 
         else 'Between 1 week and 1 month'
       end length_of_stay,
       count(*) number_of_trips,
       to_char(b.from_date,'YYYY') year   
  from TB_TRAVELITINERARY b 
  join TB_TRIP a on a.trip_id=b.trip_id   
  join TB_COUNTRY c on b.country_code= c.country_code 
  join (select rownum rn from dual connect by level < 4) d on 
     case when add_months(b.from_date,1) < b.to_date then 1
          when b.from_date+7 > b.to_date then 2
          else 3
     end = d.rn
group by c.country_name,
       a.nature_of_travel,
       case d.rn 
         when 1 then 'More than 1 month' 
         when 2 then 'Less than 1 week' 
         else 'Between 1 week and 1 month'
       end,
       to_char(b.from_date,'YYYY')
```

PL/SQL

```
DECLARE
   TYPE array_t IS VARRAY (3) OF VARCHAR2 (30);
   notarr array_t := array_t ('More than 1 month', 'Less than 1 week','Between 1 week and 1 month');
BEGIN
   FOR c1 IN (  SELECT country_name, nature_of_travel, 
                       CASE WHEN ADD_MONTHS (from_date, 1) < TO_DATE THEN 1 
                            WHEN from_date + 7 > TO_DATE THEN 2 
                            ELSE 3 
                        END los, 
                       to_char (from_date,'YYYY') yr, 
                       COUNT (*) cnt
                  FROM tb_travelitinerary a 
                  JOIN tb_trip b ON a.trip_id = b.trip_id
                  JOIN tb_country c ON a.country_code = c.country_code
              GROUP BY country_name, nature_of_travel, CASE WHEN ADD_MONTHS (from_date, 1) > TO_DATE THEN 1 WHEN from_date + 7 < TO_DATE THEN 2 ELSE 3 END, to_char (from_date,'YYYY')
              ORDER BY 4, 1, 2, 3)
   LOOP
     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(rpad(c1.COUNTRY_NAME,30)||' '||rpad(c1.NATURE_OF_TRAVEL,8)||' '||rpad(notarr(c1.LOS),27)
                          ||' '||to_char(c1.cnt,'999999990')||' '||c1.yr);
   END LOOP;
END;
```

Sample output:

SQL

[image]

PL/SQL

[image]

Comment: Thanks Mottor.. Im so so so sorry.. i accidentally made a mistake on my table columns.. TB_TRAVEL_ITINERARY should have the column TRIP_ID and not the other way around.. thats why no matter how i try ur code it doesnt work. Really appreciate ur help though.. I've updated the tables already. =X

Comment: hi mottor, r u able to provide my a sample output when running ur script? the output i get from running ur 1st script is just a list of country names. :(

Comment: @user3188291 Sample output added

Answer (score 0):

Here's a couple of alternatives - it really depends on how you want the data returned.

This first example will return one row for every combination of year, country and nature of travel that exists in the data.  With the data I have used It will not give a row for Australia and WORK because there are no trips of that type  :

```
WITH
 tb_country AS
  (SELECT 'ABW' country_code, 'Aruba' country_name FROM dual UNION ALL
   SELECT 'AFG', 'Afghanistan' FROM dual UNION ALL
   SELECT 'AGO', 'Angola' FROM dual UNION ALL
   SELECT 'AUS', 'Australia' FROM dual 
  )
,tb_travleItinerary AS
  (SELECT 1 itinerary_id, 1 trip_id, 'AUS' country_code, TO_DATE('19/05/2016','DD/MM/YYYY') date_from, TO_DATE('30/05/2016','DD/MM/YYYY') date_to FROM dual UNION ALL
   SELECT 2, 3, 'AFG', TO_DATE('10/01/2016','DD/MM/YYYY'), TO_DATE('13/01/2016','DD/MM/YYYY') FROM dual  UNION ALL
   SELECT 3, 2, 'AFG', TO_DATE('10/02/2016','DD/MM/YYYY'), TO_DATE('01/06/2016','DD/MM/YYYY') FROM dual  UNION ALL
   SELECT 4, 5, 'AFG', TO_DATE('10/03/2016','DD/MM/YYYY'), TO_DATE('13/03/2016','DD/MM/YYYY') FROM dual  UNION ALL
   SELECT 5, 7, 'AFG', TO_DATE('01/01/2016','DD/MM/YYYY'), TO_DATE('03/01/2016','DD/MM/YYYY') FROM dual  UNION ALL
   SELECT 6, 4, 'AFG', TO_DATE('01/10/2016','DD/MM/YYYY'), TO_DATE('29/10/2016','DD/MM/YYYY') FROM dual  UNION ALL
   SELECT 7, 6, 'AFG', TO_DATE('12/01/2016','DD/MM/YYYY'), TO_DATE('11/05/2016','DD/MM/YYYY') FROM dual  UNION ALL
   SELECT 8, 8, 'AFG', TO_DATE('15/01/2016','DD/MM/YYYY'), TO_DATE('18/01/2016','DD/MM/YYYY') FROM dual  UNION ALL
   SELECT 9, 9, 'AFG', TO_DATE('22/01/2016','DD/MM/YYYY'), TO_DATE('13/01/2016','DD/MM/YYYY') FROM dual  UNION ALL
   SELECT 10, 10, 'AFG', TO_DATE('31/01/2016','DD/MM/YYYY'), TO_DATE('18/02/2016','DD/MM/YYYY') FROM dual  UNION ALL
   SELECT 11, 11, 'AFG', TO_DATE('02/02/2016','DD/MM/YYYY'), TO_DATE('13/10/2016','DD/MM/YYYY') FROM dual  UNION ALL
   SELECT 12, 12, 'AFG', TO_DATE('10/02/2016','DD/MM/YYYY'), TO_DATE('11/02/2016','DD/MM/YYYY') FROM dual
  )  
,tb_trip AS
  (SELECT 1 trip_id, 'HOLIDAY' nature_of_travel FROM dual UNION ALL
   SELECT 2, 'STUDY' FROM dual UNION ALL
   SELECT 3, 'WORK' FROM dual UNION ALL
   SELECT 4, 'HOLIDAY' FROM dual UNION ALL
   SELECT 5, 'STUDY' FROM dual UNION ALL
   SELECT 6, 'WORK' FROM dual UNION ALL
   SELECT 7, 'HOLIDAY' FROM dual UNION ALL
   SELECT 8, 'STUDY' FROM dual UNION ALL
   SELECT 9, 'WORK' FROM dual UNION ALL
   SELECT 10, 'HOLIDAY' FROM dual UNION ALL
   SELECT 11, 'STUDY' FROM dual UNION ALL
   SELECT 12, 'WORK' FROM dual 
  )
SELECT
 country_name
,nature_of_travel
--,length_of_stay
,year
,SUM(less_than_one_week)         count_less_than_one_week
,SUM(more_than_one_month)        count_more_than_one_month
,SUM(other_duration)             count_other_duration
FROM
 (SELECT
   c.country_name
  ,t.nature_of_travel
  ,CASE 
    WHEN ti.date_to - ti.date_from < 7 
     THEN 'Less than 1 week'
    WHEN ti.date_to - ti.date_from > 30  --note : you need to dfine what you mean by a month
     THEN 'More than 1 month'
    ELSE 'Between 1 week and 1 month'
   END                                   length_of_stay
  ,CASE
    WHEN ti.date_to - ti.date_from < 7 
     THEN 1
    ELSE 0
   END                                   less_than_one_week
  ,CASE
    WHEN ti.date_to - ti.date_from > 30 
     THEN 1
    ELSE 0
   END                                   more_than_one_month
  ,CASE
    WHEN ti.date_to - ti.date_from BETWEEN 7 AND 30 
     THEN 1
    ELSE 0
   END                                   other_duration
  ,TO_CHAR(ti.date_from,'YYYY')          year
  FROM
   tb_country                  c
  ,tb_travleItinerary          ti
  ,tb_trip                     t
  WHERE 1=1
  AND c.country_code = ti.country_code
  AND ti.trip_id = t.trip_id
 ) raw_data
WHERE 1=1
GROUP BY
 country_name
,nature_of_travel
,year
ORDER BY
 country_name
,nature_of_travel
,year
;
```

[image]

This second example will return one row for every combination of year and country that exists in the data.  For each row you will get counts of all trip types and durations, even if the counts are zero :

```
WITH
 tb_country AS
  (SELECT 'ABW' country_code, 'Aruba' country_name FROM dual UNION ALL
   SELECT 'AFG', 'Afghanistan' FROM dual UNION ALL
   SELECT 'AGO', 'Angola' FROM dual UNION ALL
   SELECT 'AUS', 'Australia' FROM dual 
  )
,tb_travleItinerary AS
  (SELECT 1 itinerary_id, 1 trip_id, 'AUS' country_code, TO_DATE('19/05/2016','DD/MM/YYYY') date_from, TO_DATE('30/05/2016','DD/MM/YYYY') date_to FROM dual UNION ALL
   SELECT 2, 3, 'AFG', TO_DATE('10/01/2016','DD/MM/YYYY'), TO_DATE('13/01/2016','DD/MM/YYYY') FROM dual  UNION ALL
   SELECT 3, 2, 'AFG', TO_DATE('10/02/2016','DD/MM/YYYY'), TO_DATE('01/06/2016','DD/MM/YYYY') FROM dual  UNION ALL
   SELECT 4, 5, 'AFG', TO_DATE('10/03/2016','DD/MM/YYYY'), TO_DATE('13/03/2016','DD/MM/YYYY') FROM dual  UNION ALL
   SELECT 5, 7, 'AFG', TO_DATE('01/01/2016','DD/MM/YYYY'), TO_DATE('03/01/2016','DD/MM/YYYY') FROM dual  UNION ALL
   SELECT 6, 4, 'AFG', TO_DATE('01/10/2016','DD/MM/YYYY'), TO_DATE('29/10/2016','DD/MM/YYYY') FROM dual  UNION ALL
   SELECT 7, 6, 'AFG', TO_DATE('12/01/2016','DD/MM/YYYY'), TO_DATE('11/05/2016','DD/MM/YYYY') FROM dual  UNION ALL
   SELECT 8, 8, 'AFG', TO_DATE('15/01/2016','DD/MM/YYYY'), TO_DATE('18/01/2016','DD/MM/YYYY') FROM dual  UNION ALL
   SELECT 9, 9, 'AFG', TO_DATE('22/01/2016','DD/MM/YYYY'), TO_DATE('13/01/2016','DD/MM/YYYY') FROM dual  UNION ALL
   SELECT 10, 10, 'AFG', TO_DATE('31/01/2016','DD/MM/YYYY'), TO_DATE('18/02/2016','DD/MM/YYYY') FROM dual  UNION ALL
   SELECT 11, 11, 'AFG', TO_DATE('02/02/2016','DD/MM/YYYY'), TO_DATE('13/10/2016','DD/MM/YYYY') FROM dual  UNION ALL
   SELECT 12, 12, 'AFG', TO_DATE('10/02/2016','DD/MM/YYYY'), TO_DATE('11/02/2016','DD/MM/YYYY') FROM dual
  )  
,tb_trip AS
  (SELECT 1 trip_id, 'HOLIDAY' nature_of_travel FROM dual UNION ALL
   SELECT 2, 'STUDY' FROM dual UNION ALL
   SELECT 3, 'WORK' FROM dual UNION ALL
   SELECT 4, 'HOLIDAY' FROM dual UNION ALL
   SELECT 5, 'STUDY' FROM dual UNION ALL
   SELECT 6, 'WORK' FROM dual UNION ALL
   SELECT 7, 'HOLIDAY' FROM dual UNION ALL
   SELECT 8, 'STUDY' FROM dual UNION ALL
   SELECT 9, 'WORK' FROM dual UNION ALL
   SELECT 10, 'HOLIDAY' FROM dual UNION ALL
   SELECT 11, 'STUDY' FROM dual UNION ALL
   SELECT 12, 'WORK' FROM dual 
  )
SELECT
 country_name
,year
,(SELECT count(*)
  FROM tb_travleItinerary ti2, tb_trip  tt
  WHERE ti2.country_code = raw_data.country_code
  AND TO_CHAR(ti2.date_from,'YYYY') = raw_data.year
  AND ti2.trip_id = tt.trip_id 
  AND tt.nature_of_travel = 'HOLIDAY'
  AND ti2.date_to - ti2.date_from < 7
)                                                holiday_lt_1_week
,(SELECT count(*)
  FROM tb_travleItinerary ti2, tb_trip  tt
  WHERE ti2.country_code = raw_data.country_code
  AND TO_CHAR(ti2.date_from,'YYYY') = raw_data.year
  AND ti2.trip_id = tt.trip_id 
  AND tt.nature_of_travel = 'HOLIDAY'
  AND ti2.date_to - ti2.date_from > 30
)                                                holiday_gt_1_month
,(SELECT count(*)
  FROM tb_travleItinerary ti2, tb_trip  tt
  WHERE ti2.country_code = raw_data.country_code
  AND TO_CHAR(ti2.date_from,'YYYY') = raw_data.year
  AND ti2.trip_id = tt.trip_id 
  AND tt.nature_of_travel = 'HOLIDAY'
  AND ti2.date_to - ti2.date_from BETWEEN 7 AND 30
)                                                holiday_other
,(SELECT count(*)
  FROM tb_travleItinerary ti2, tb_trip  tt
  WHERE ti2.country_code = raw_data.country_code
  AND TO_CHAR(ti2.date_from,'YYYY') = raw_data.year
  AND ti2.trip_id = tt.trip_id 
  AND tt.nature_of_travel = 'WORK'
  AND ti2.date_to - ti2.date_from < 7
)                                                work_lt_1_week
,(SELECT count(*)
  FROM tb_travleItinerary ti2, tb_trip  tt
  WHERE ti2.country_code = raw_data.country_code
  AND TO_CHAR(ti2.date_from,'YYYY') = raw_data.year
  AND ti2.trip_id = tt.trip_id 
  AND tt.nature_of_travel = 'WORK'
  AND ti2.date_to - ti2.date_from > 30
)                                                work_gt_1_month
,(SELECT count(*)
  FROM tb_travleItinerary ti2, tb_trip  tt
  WHERE ti2.country_code = raw_data.country_code
  AND TO_CHAR(ti2.date_from,'YYYY') = raw_data.year
  AND ti2.trip_id = tt.trip_id 
  AND tt.nature_of_travel = 'WORK'
  AND ti2.date_to - ti2.date_from BETWEEN 7 AND 30
)                                                work_other
,(SELECT count(*)
  FROM tb_travleItinerary ti2, tb_trip  tt
  WHERE ti2.country_code = raw_data.country_code
  AND TO_CHAR(ti2.date_from,'YYYY') = raw_data.year
  AND ti2.trip_id = tt.trip_id 
  AND tt.nature_of_travel = 'STUDY'
  AND ti2.date_to - ti2.date_from < 7
)                                                study_lt_1_week
,(SELECT count(*)
  FROM tb_travleItinerary ti2, tb_trip  tt
  WHERE ti2.country_code = raw_data.country_code
  AND TO_CHAR(ti2.date_from,'YYYY') = raw_data.year
  AND ti2.trip_id = tt.trip_id 
  AND tt.nature_of_travel = 'STUDY'
  AND ti2.date_to - ti2.date_from > 30
)                                                study_gt_1_month
,(SELECT count(*)
  FROM tb_travleItinerary ti2, tb_trip  tt
  WHERE ti2.country_code = raw_data.country_code
  AND TO_CHAR(ti2.date_from,'YYYY') = raw_data.year
  AND ti2.trip_id = tt.trip_id 
  AND tt.nature_of_travel = 'STUDY'
  AND ti2.date_to - ti2.date_from BETWEEN 7 AND 30
)                                                study_other
FROM
 (SELECT DISTINCT
   c.country_name
  ,c.country_code
  ,TO_CHAR(ti.date_from,'YYYY')          year
  FROM
   tb_country                  c
  ,tb_travleItinerary          ti
  WHERE 1=1
  AND c.country_code = ti.country_code
 ) raw_data
WHERE 1=1
```

[image]